# Does ASP.NET Core RC2 still rely on DNX at all

Tags: visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, dotnet-cli

I have started upgrading to **ASP.NET Core RC2**, following the [instructions](http://dotnet.github.io/docs/core-concepts/dnx-migration.html) provided. However, I'm confused - it seems as though there was no mention of uninstalling **DNX** or any of the other CLIs (**DNVM** and **DNU**). Does that need to be uninstalled, or does **RC2** rely on it somehow?

After following the instructions and rebooting, I still have a `dnx.exe` in my task manager and a `.dnx` folder even though I deleted it as part of the upgrade. I can literally delete the entire `.dnx` directory, runtime and all - and after opening **Visual Studio** it comes back after the `dotnet` **CLI** starts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .NET Core RC2 and ASP.NET Core does not rely on DNX at all. Afair there is a compatibility layer during the last month, but that should be gone as well.

If your projects build with RC2, then you can safely uninstall all ASP.NET 5 tooling (dnx, dnvm, ...) and delete their caches. Also deleting the nuget cache does not harm and reduce space (since the actual parts will restore on next opportunity).

Your problem with Visual Studio is that most probably the VS tooling for ASP.NET is still there. I had problems uninstalling them, but once done, you can use Visual Studio without encountering DNX or "ASP.NET 5" projects.

Comment: I think the issue I was having is that the in the `project.json` the `frameworks` was set to `dnx46`.

Comment: And watchout for the global.json (the sdk might be there). I fell into that thing. Also the xprojs need an update. VS tooling/migration could be so easy but is not done.